# How can I disable the loading of design-view while opening a form in WPF?

Tags: wpf

How can I disable the loading of design-view while opening a form in [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)?

Actually, I want to set the [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language)-view as the opening tab in design form. It takes so much time to load and the form was locked until I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button and wait for seconds. There must be an easy way to set this.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XAML -> Miscellaneous -> Always open document in full XAML view

Answer (score 0):

You can maximize the code view, then the next time you open the file, only the code view will appear.

Comment: yes, this is the option that I am using right now but, I need a more stable solution :/ thanks anyway.